# installing rails on mac yosemite 10.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, installation

OS Yosemite 10.10
I was building ror development enviorment on my laptop.
following [installrails.com][1] steps, and now stuck at install rails. 
someone helps would be great. thanks

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing rails:     ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150329-3365-1fd5w4t.rb extconf.rb checking if the C
> ```
>
> compiler accepts ... yes checking if the C compiler accepts
>   -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no Building nokogiri using packaged libraries. checking for gzdopen() in
>   -lz... yes checking for iconv... yes
>   ************************************************************************ IMPORTANT NOTICE:
>
> Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.2 with the
>   following patches applied:
>     - 0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch
>     - 0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch
>
> Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
>   updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
>   to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
>   reinstall nokogiri as follows:
>
> ```
> gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
>     [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
>     [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]
> ```
>
> If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:
>
> ```
> bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
> bundle install
> ```
>
> Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
>   versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
>   ************************************************************************ Extracting libxml2-2.9.2.tar.gz into
>   tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.2... OK Running patch
>   with
>   /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxml2/0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch...
>   Running 'patch' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK Running patch with
>   /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxml2/0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch...
>   Running 'patch' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK Running 'configure' for
>   libxml2 2.9.2... OK Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK Running
>   'install' for libxml2 2.9.2... OK Activating libxml2 2.9.2 (from
>   /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0/libxml2/2.9.2)...
>   ************************************************************************ IMPORTANT NOTICE:
>
> Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxslt-1.1.28 with the
>   following patches applied:
>     - 0001-Adding-doc-update-related-to-1.1.28.patch
>     - 0002-Fix-a-couple-of-places-where-f-printf-parameters-wer.patch
>     - 0003-Initialize-pseudo-random-number-generator-with-curre.patch
>     - 0004-EXSLT-function-str-replace-is-broken-as-is.patch
>     - 0006-Fix-str-padding-to-work-with-UTF-8-strings.patch
>     - 0007-Separate-function-for-predicate-matching-in-patterns.patch
>     - 0008-Fix-direct-pattern-matching.patch
>     - 0009-Fix-certain-patterns-with-predicates.patch
>     - 0010-Fix-handling-of-UTF-8-strings-in-EXSLT-crypto-module.patch
>     - 0013-Memory-leak-in-xsltCompileIdKeyPattern-error-path.patch
>     - 0014-Fix-for-bug-436589.patch
>     - 0015-Fix-mkdir-for-mingw.patch
>
> Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
>   updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
>   to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
>   reinstall nokogiri as follows:
>
> ```
> gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
>     [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
>     [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]
> ```
>
> If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:
>
> ```
> bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
> bundle install
> ```
>
> ************************************************************************ Extracting libxslt-1.1.28.tar.gz into
>   tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0/ports/libxslt/1.1.28... OK Running patch
>   with
>   /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0001-Adding-doc-update-related-to-1.1.28.patch...
>   Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK Running patch with
>   /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0002-Fix-a-couple-of-places-where-f-printf-parameters-wer.patch...
>   Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK Running patch with
>   /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0003-Initialize-pseudo-random-number-generator-with-curre.patch...
>   Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK Running patch with
>   /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0004-EXSLT-function-str-replace-is-broken-as-is.patch...
>   Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK Running patch with
>   /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0006-Fix-str-padding-to-work-with-UTF-8-strings.patch...
>   Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK Running patch with
>   /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0007-Separate-function-for-predicate-matching-in-patterns.patch...
>   Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK Running patch with
>   /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0008-Fix-direct-pattern-matching.patch...
>   Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK Running patch with
>   /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0009-Fix-certain-patterns-with-predicates.patch...
>   Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK Running patch with
>   /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0010-Fix-handling-of-UTF-8-strings-in-EXSLT-crypto-module.patch...
>   Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK Running patch with
>   /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0013-Memory-leak-in-xsltCompileIdKeyPattern-error-path.patch...
>   Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK Running patch with
>   /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0014-Fix-for-bug-436589.patch...
>   Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK Running patch with
>   /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/patches/libxslt/0015-Fix-mkdir-for-mingw.patch...
>   Running 'patch' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK Running 'configure' for
>   libxslt 1.1.28... OK Running 'compile' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK
>   Running 'install' for libxslt 1.1.28... OK Activating libxslt 1.1.28
>   (from
>   /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports/x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0/libxslt/1.1.28)...
>   checking for main() in -llzma... yes checking for xmlParseDoc() in
>   libxml/parser.h... yes checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in
>   libxslt/xslt.h... yes checking for exsltFuncRegister() in
>   libexslt/exslt.h... yes checking for xmlHasFeature()... yes checking
>   for xmlFirstElementChild()... yes checking for
>   xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes checking for
>   xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes checking for
>   xmlRelaxNGSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes checking for
>   xmlSchemaSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes checking for
>   xmlSchemaSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes creating Makefile
>
> make "DESTDIR=" clean
>
> make "DESTDIR=" compiling html_document.c compiling
>   html_element_description.c compiling html_entity_lookup.c compiling
>   html_sax_parser_context.c compiling html_sax_push_parser.c compiling
>   nokogiri.c compiling xml_attr.c compiling xml_attribute_decl.c
>   compiling xml_cdata.c compiling xml_comment.c compiling xml_document.c
>   compiling xml_document_fragment.c compiling xml_dtd.c compiling
>   xml_element_content.c compiling xml_element_decl.c compiling
>   xml_encoding_handler.c compiling xml_entity_decl.c compiling
>   xml_entity_reference.c compiling xml_io.c compiling
>   xml_libxml2_hacks.c compiling xml_namespace.c compiling xml_node.c
>   xml_node.c:168:15: warning: 14 enumeration values not handled in
>   switch: 'XML_ATTRIBUTE_NODE', 'XML_ENTITY_NODE',
>   'XML_DOCUMENT_NODE'... [-Wswitch]
>         switch (reparentee->type) {
>                 ^ xml_node.c:186:15: warning: 15 enumeration values not handled in switch: 'XML_ATTRIBUTE_NODE', 'XML_ENTITY_NODE',
>   'XML_DOCUMENT_NODE'... [-Wswitch]
>         switch (reparentee->type) {
>                 ^ xml_node.c:197:15: warning: 19 enumeration values not handled in switch: 'XML_ELEMENT_NODE', 'XML_ATTRIBUTE_NODE',
>   'XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE'... [-Wswitch]
>         switch (reparentee->type) {
>                 ^ xml_node.c:165:13: warning: 14 enumeration values not handled in switch: 'XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE', 'XML_ENTITY_NODE',
>   'XML_PI_NODE'... [-Wswitch]
>       switch (parent->type) {
>               ^ 4 warnings generated. compiling xml_node_set.c compiling xml_processing_instruction.c compiling xml_reader.c compiling
>   xml_relax_ng.c compiling xml_sax_parser.c compiling
>   xml_sax_parser_context.c compiling xml_sax_push_parser.c compiling
>   xml_schema.c compiling xml_syntax_error.c compiling xml_text.c
>   compiling xml_xpath_context.c compiling xslt_stylesheet.c
>   xslt_stylesheet.c:217:21: warning: incompatible pointer to integer
>   conversion passing 'void *' to parameter of type 'VALUE' (aka
>   'unsigned long') [-Wint-conversion]
>       Data_Get_Struct(ctxt->style->_private, nokogiriXsltStylesheetTuple,
>                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1044:41:
>   note: expanded from macro 'Data_Get_Struct'
>       ((sval) = (type*)rb_data_object_get(obj))
>                                           ^ /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1189:26:
>   note: passing argument to parameter 'obj' here
>   rb_data_object_get(VALUE obj)
>                            ^ xslt_stylesheet.c:230:21: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'void *' to
>   parameter of type 'VALUE' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wint-conversion]
>       Data_Get_Struct(ctxt->style->_private, nokogiriXsltStylesheetTuple,
>                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1044:41:
>   note: expanded from macro 'Data_Get_Struct'
>       ((sval) = (type*)rb_data_object_get(obj))
>                                           ^ /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/ruby.h:1189:26:
>   note: passing argument to parameter 'obj' here
>   rb_data_object_get(VALUE obj)
>                            ^ 2 warnings generated. linking shared-object nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L/Users/haven/.sm/pkg/active/lib' Cleaning files only used during
>   build. rm -rf
>   /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0/ports
>   rmdir -p
>   /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0 rm -rf
>   /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/ports
>
> make "DESTDIR=" install make: /usr/local/bin/gmkdir: No such file or
>   directory make: *** [.RUBYARCHDIR.-.nokogiri.time] Error 1
>
> make install failed, exit code 2
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for
>   inspection. Results logged to
>   /Users/jasonyang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out

Comment: Use this guide instead: https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.10-yosemite

Comment: I have the same issue, I think we should focus on the error logs:
    make: /usr/local/bin/gmkdir: No such file or directory
    make: *** [.RUBYARCHDIR.-.nokogiri.time] Error 1

In my case, it's an issue specific for ruby-2.2.1 since with 2.2.0 the same version of nokogiri installs just fine.

Comment: Indeed rvm ruby executable was broken, I fixed the issue with a rvm remove and reinstalled 2.2.1

Answer (score 5):

You need to install **coreutils** for fixing this.

With MacPorts:

```
sudo port install coreutils
```

For Homebrew:

```
sudo brew install coreutils
```